# Jenkins - Login Page shows up, but getting securityRealm / finishLogin ErrorID=e160bxxx-aaa-yyy-zzzz

Tags: security, jenkins, ldap, stack-trace, jenkins-2

**Jenkins version**: 2.89.4 / 2.89.4.2-rolling

I can see the login page (clicking right top `Log in` link). Sometime it brings the login page (where a user can enter username / password) -OR- it's taking me straight to an error.. in either case.

**Error:**

In the address bar, I see this URL value:

http://jenkins-dev-server:8080/securityRealm/finishLogin?code=bc2c6a5a-b898-4a6b-96h7-e7jhcba59ytg

```
An error occurred processing your request. Ask your Jenkins administrator to look up details. ErrorID=gh425da7-0y78-4068-b2h9-c2bed48ke6sa

Stack trace suppressed by the suppress stack trace plugin
```

One of the job's status before this happened was showing FAILED (Red ball) but looking into the job's console output shows NO "error|failed|fail|aborted|fatal|memory" related errors (case in-sensitive). The last line in the console output is just a valid expected output (for ex: `echo  "hello world"`) nothing after that.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like, Jenkins home's mount (`df -kvh ${JENKINS_HOME}`) was 100% full. I know! new to the team.

- Will implement some good monitoring as soon as I get some elevated
  access.